# joomla message shows "error", "warning" text

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Joomla message displays "Warning" or "Error" word beforee message. Is it possible to remove it?

My custom template contains

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
```

I am using default login form. When user doesn't enter his credentials, then error message appears:

```
Error
Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.
```

On another form it shows *Warning* and message on the next line.

I do not want this text "error" or "warning" appear. Why it appears?

Comment: The html surrounding "Error" and "Warning" will have a very specific class set to it that you can set to `display:none;` using css. I don't remember the class offhand, but it shouldn't conflict anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you.
Please add this code

> while(ob_get_level()){
>
> ```
>        ob_end_clean(); }
> ```

before
this line:

> ```
>        echo $error;
> ```

in

> function ajax() of file helper.php

Sorry i cant say clearly which line because maybe you are using different version.

This solution can't be applied for same error of BT Login, if they exits, example: Register...
I hope it will work for you.
Thanks so much